# WorkManager : getInstance() is Deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated, android-workmanager, workmanagers

WorkManager.getInstance() is Deprecated in version 2.1.0

dependency :

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.1.0'
```

What are the changes in this method or any other ways?

Comment: I am sharing this thing for knowledge purpose. Google gives results of stackoverflow  before official websites. Do let me know why down-vote?

Comment: I'm OK having a question like this here if it helps developers. (upvoted it)

However, searching for "WorkManager.getInstance() is Deprecated in version 2.1.0" returns links to the release notes and to the documentation. I usually try to avoid duplication in these cases, because it can be a maintenance cost in the future.

If you think that WorkManager's documentation needs improvement, please file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the solution on documentation as follow:

> This method is deprecated.
>
> Call [getInstance(Context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#getInstance(android.content.Context)) instead.

Where **Context** is used for on-demand initialization.

WorkManager v2.1 introduces a new way to customize its configuration. While with the previous version it was necessary to create a new configuration and initialize WorkManager during the app startup, v2.1 adds a new "on demand" initialization.
This means that WorkManager is initialized (with the default or the custom) initialization the first time that the app calls the [`getInstance(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#getInstance(android.content.Context)) method.

The `Context` in this case is used to retrieve the application object and see if it implements the `Configuration.Provider` interface.

More information are available in [WorkManager's documentation on custom configuration](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand).

This change is documented in [WorkManager's release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0) (this was introduced in WorkManager v2.1-alpha01) and it's explained there why it's better to use the new `getInstance(Context)` method even if you're not using on demand initialization.

Note : Whenever you change or update dependency version, please go through the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0)

Answer (score 6):

According to [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager), you must use this way:

```
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
```